# WebLogic 12c commons-logging logfile per app

Tags: java, logging, weblogic12c

I have configured WebLogic 12c to make use of the commons-logging library using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24428/config_logs.htm#autoId12) guide. I'm using the (default) JDK logger.

All my logging lands in the server log, though I have specified an **application** log file in my deployment plan. The file is created, but completely different (JSP) logging written to the file:

```
####<4-mrt-2014 13:17:15 uur CET> <Info> <ServletContext-/root> <WX00000219> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1393935435877> <BEA-000000> <JspServlet: param verbose initialized to: true>
```

Anyone with some experience in logging to files per application using commons-logging?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting weblogic-application.xml in application.

weblogic-application.xml should have entries like

```
    <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name> 
    <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name> 
    </prefer-application-packages>
```